# Using GROUPing or ROLLUP rather than SUMing every column

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

I am currently looking for a way to achieve what this query is doing without using `SUM` for every column and, if possible, `GROUP`ing or using `ROLLUP` or something similar.

This query gives me a total for orders across all currencies.

```
SELECT DATE, TYPE, SUM(orders), SUM(qty),
SUM(shipped_orders), SUM(shipped_qty), SUM(return_qty),
SUM(shipped_minus_returns_units)
    FROM daily_report 
    WHERE `date` >= '2015-07-01' AND `date` <= '2015-07-29'
GROUP BY DATE ASC, TYPE ASC;
```

My current query looks like this:

```
SELECT DATE, currency, TYPE, orders, qty, shipped_orders, shipped_qty, return_qty,
shipped_minus_returns_units
    FROM daily_report 
    WHERE `date` >= '2015-07-01' AND `date` <= '2015-07-29'
GROUP BY DATE ASC, TYPE ASC, currency ASC;
```

which returns this DB table view:

[image: Daily Report DB View]

```
CREATE TABLE `daily_report` (
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `currency` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('customer','exchanges') NOT NULL,
  `orders` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `qty` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `value` decimal(9,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `value_ex_ship` decimal(9,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `average_order_value` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,
  `average_item_value` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,
  `average_item_per_order` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,
  `shipped_orders` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `shipped_qty` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `shipped_value` decimal(9,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `net_shipped_value` decimal(9,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `return_qty` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `return_value` decimal(9,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `returns_to_shipped` decimal(9,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `shipped_minus_returns_units` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `shipped_minus_returns_value` decimal(9,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`date`,`currency`,`type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Is there a way to total up these columns using group rather than `SUM`'ing everything?

Comment: I'd keep the first query but with `GROUP BY DATE ASC, TYPE ASC, currency ASC ;`. The 2nd query makes no sense. It's even invalid SQL, try it with [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) setting on.

Comment: @ypercube Thanks for your comment. So maybe my best bet is to stick with the `SUM`ing then? My first query works it's just I thought maybe some clever grouping rather than `SUM`ing every column would be the more efficient way to do this. I don't actually need the `currency ASC` in the first query at all. Out of interest what is invalid about the second query?

Comment: First, I think you need the `currency` in the `group by`. I can't figure how adding 100 euros with 100 dollars will make 200 (of what?) a sensible result. If the columns used in the query do not have money-data but only orders/quantities, then it's fine.

Comment: For the 2nd query, the not-sensible thing is that you have columsn in the `SELECT` list (orders, quantity, etc.), that are not in the `GROUP BY` list and are not aggregated. For any combination of date, type, currency you'll have many rows but the group by will "collapse"/gather them in one row in the result. These (many) rows will have many orders, quantity, etc. values but only one will (arbitrarily) chosen and displayed in the result.

Comment: It would also help if you added the `SHOW CREATE TABLE daily_report;` output in the question. Some of my comments depend on the unique constraints that you have on the table.

Comment: @ypercube Table DDL information added to the question.

Comment: OK, now the 2nd query makes some sense (it will at least produce sensible results) because it will return all rows of the table. But you don't need `GROUP BY` in the 2nd query, a simple select would give same results. So, the issue is that you want all rows of the table **and** some aggregations (sums)?

Comment: @ypercube Yes. In the screenshot attached i'd like to get the total of all four currencies listed and my question was - could I do that with GROUPing rather than just SUMing all columns. Maybe it's not possible...or maybe it's sub-optimal.

Comment: In other DBMS, you could use `GROUPING SETS` but MySQL has only `WITH ROLLUP` which will give you more results than you need: groups by date and type - which you want - but also group by date and also a total group by. Your other option is to have a normal select (without group by) and UNION ALL to your first query.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the ideal solution would need `GROUP BY GROUPING SETS` which is not available in MySQL.

Your two options are to use

- `WITH ROLLUP`:

  ```
  SELECT date, type, currency, 
         SUM(orders) AS orders, SUM(qty) AS qty, 
         SUM(shipped_orders) AS shipped_orders, 
         SUM(shipped_qty) AS shipped_qty, 
         SUM(return_qty) AS return_qty,
         SUM(shipped_minus_returns_units) AS shipped_minus_returns_units
  FROM daily_report 
  WHERE date >= '2015-07-01' AND date <= '2015-07-29'
  GROUP BY date, type, currency
    WITH ROLLUP ;
  ```
- two queries, one simple and one with the aggregations needed and `UNION ALL`:

  ```
  SELECT date, type, currency, 
         orders, qty, shipped_orders, 
         shipped_qty, return_qty, shipped_minus_returns_units
  FROM daily_report 
  WHERE date >= '2015-07-01' AND date <= '2015-07-29'

  UNION ALL

  SELECT date, type, NULL, 
         SUM(orders), SUM(qty), SUM(shipped_orders),
         SUM(shipped_qty), SUM(return_qty), SUM(shipped_minus_returns_units)
  FROM daily_report 
  WHERE date >= '2015-07-01' AND date <= '2015-07-29'
  GROUP BY date, type 

  ORDER BY date, type, currency ;
  ```

The first option will have more groupings than you need (per date only and a single total in the end).